# Unity tweak tool doesn't apply theme 16.04

Tags: unity-tweak-tool

I've installed 16.04 on my Asus UX21 laptop. I installed Unity Tweak Tool and added the snwh/pulp repository (from Noobslab website) so I could install the Paper theme and icon set.

Sometimes when I log in, the Ambiance theme is active and Unity Tweak Tool is unresponsive when trying to revert back to the Paper theme. A reboot usually solves the problem.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Does this happen for other themes too?

Comment: Not sure. Will give it a go.

Comment: Okay. I am not sure if it is a bug with the Unity Tweak Tool or with the theme.

Comment: The problem is I don't really know how to recreate it. I guess time will tell, but I'll post here if I find anything. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit, on my Acer laptop alongside Windows, I've also installed unity tweak tool and the paper theme too. It works without any problem, the only problem is i can't read some fonts in some applications because the fonts and the background have a very close colors.  unity tweak tool works without any noticeable problem

Comment: Try setting the default theme in tweak and then change it from the terminal with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'paper-icon-theme'` now if it crashes at boot your theme should stay the same.

Comment: Right, it happens when ever I shut down and cold boot. It doesn't happen when rebooting. Mark, I've tried your suggestion but that did nothing. It isn't limited to the theme - I've tried some others and exactly the same thing happens.